# 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, batch-file

In Win 2003 I execute command

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\robocopy" "q:\SQLBackup" "\\SQLBackups\MyDB"  /Z /S /MIR
```

I am getting an error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What could I do?
I don't want to add C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\ to a PATH environment variable.

Comment: Then every time set the path manually by `set path` command in shell command.

Comment: How are you executing that command?  Because it should work as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to give the path of ROBOCOPY as part of the command. Your syntax is off a little. Change your code to

`robocopy q:\SQLBackup \\SQLBackups\MyDB /Z /S /MIR`

Comment: Change the directory first to C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\ by using `cd C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\`... and then use @CharlieRB's answer

Comment: Robocopy is not installed by default on Windows Server 2003.  It needs to be added with the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit, and it appears that the path is not added automatically on installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to add the directory to your path, the simplest option would be to copy robocopy.exe to %WINDIR%\system32.  Alternatively, you could make a hardlink pointing to it.